# Вызов функции Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Есть функция для вывода многоуровневого меню сайта `showCatMenu();`. Необходимо её передать в шаблон. Если делать так:

```
$catalogMenu = $smarty->assign('catalogMenu', $goods->showCatMenu($r));
```

то в шаблоне появится меню в самом верху страницы. Как вставить меню в блок div в шаблоне *.tpl

```
<div id="catalog-menu">
    <div class="catalog-menu">
        {$тут_вызов_функции_для_вывода_меню}
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPD:**

```
 function showCatMenu($arr,$parent_id = 0) {

        if(empty($arr[$parent_id])) {
            return;
        }
        echo '<ul>';

        for($i = 0; $i < count($arr[$parent_id]);$i++) {
            echo '<li><a href="?category_id='.$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id'].
                        '&parent_id='.$parent_id.'">'
                        .$arr[$parent_id][$i]['title'].'</a>';
            $this->showCatMenu($arr,$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id']);
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы вызываете `$smarty->assign` - создается шаблонная переменная `catalogMenu` и ей присваивается вывод из функции `$goods->showCatMenu($r)`. Чтобы вывести этот HTML код - достаточно в шаблоне поправить следующее:

```
<div id="catalog-menu">
    <div class="catalog-menu">
        {$catalogMenu}
    </div>
</div>
```

Учтите, что функция `$goods->showCatMenu($r)` должна возвращать именно HTML код.

В вопросе вы не пояснили, что именно выводиться

> появится меню в самом верху страницы

HTML код или само меню?

Может быть такое, что в коде меню присутствуют стили, которые переносят меню вверх страницы при визуальном отображении?

**UPD:**

Функция осуществляет вывод результата выполнения, вместо его возвращения при вызове. Нужно исправить функцию хотя бы так:

```
function showCatMenu($arr,$parent_id = 0) {
    $html_return = "";
    if(empty($arr[$parent_id])) {
        return;
    }
    $html_return .= '<ul>';

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr[$parent_id]);$i++) {
        $html_return .= '<li><a href="?category_id='.$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id'].
                    '&parent_id='.$parent_id.'">'
                    .$arr[$parent_id][$i]['title'].'</a>';
        $this->showCatMenu($arr,$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id']);
        $html_return .= '</li>';
    }
    $html_return .= '</ul>';
    return $html_return;
}
```

Comment: Вот в этом то вся и проблема. Я так и делал, до того, как задать вопрос. Но функция `showCatMenu($r);` вызывается, когда мы создаем шаблонную переменную, по этому меню и появляется вверху, до вывода всего шаблона. Другими словами, я оставляю место, куда вставлять  меню в шаблоне пустым, а в файле обработчике прописываю `$smarty->assign('catalogMenu', $goods->showCatMenu($r));` и у меня сразу выводится меню, даже без вывода его в шаблоне командой {$catalogMenu}

Comment: Значит эта функция не возвращает результат выполнения, а делает `echo "<SOME_HTML_TAGS>";`. Исправьте функцию и всё получиться.

Comment: Не могу сообразить что не так, обновил вопрос, прикрепил код функции `showCatMenu`, посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду знать